What is the meaning of this definition?
Let $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ the Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing functions and $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ the space of tempered distributions. Let $f$ be such that $f^{\gamma} \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ for every $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$. I came across the following definition:
$$W_{\gamma}:= \{\phi \in \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d}): f^{\gamma}\phi \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})\}$$
What is the meaning of this definition? If $\phi$ is a distribution, then its product by a smooth function is defined in such a way that $\langle f^{\gamma}\phi, h\rangle = \langle \phi, f^{\gamma}h\rangle$ for every $h \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$. But what does it mean to say that $f^{\gamma}\phi$ is an element of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$?

To say that $f^\gamma \phi$ is in $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ means there exists an $L^2$ function $g$ whose corresponding distribution (defined by making $\langle g, \phi\rangle$ act as the $L^2$ inner product) is precisely $f^\gamma \phi$. So $\langle f^\gamma \phi, \psi\rangle = \langle g, \psi\rangle_{L^2}$ for any test function $\psi$

The notation is unclear: what is $f$ at the power gamma. Is it just a family parametrized by gamma or really the pointwise gamma power? The latter would need the function to be positive everywhere.
